# Discord Bot - Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to create a Discord bot and add some commands to it but it seems to not work.
I added the print statement to figure out if the command was added, but it returns None. Calling "!hello" in the Discord channel raises CommandNotFound.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
TOKEN = [some token]


@client.command
async def hello(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.channel.send(arg)

print(client.get_command("hello"))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are missing parentheses after `@client.command`, just add `()` to it like this:

```py
@client.command()
```

Answer (score 1):

ctx.channel.send() needs to be replaced by ctx.send()
and as loloToster just said, @client.command needs () behind it
so the final code would be:

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
TOKEN = [some token]


@client.command()
async def hello(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

print(client.get_command("hello"))

client.run(TOKEN)
```